# Issues monerod downloading a node on debian

Tags: monerod

I am having issues downloading a monero node.
Here are some code prints.
It is too much to paste here.

https://postimg.cc/gwzdcQr9
https://postimg.cc/3yfM8wPp

I am running this through clearnet you guys can see my ip so why am I still not allowed to download the node?

Examples of errors:
I no available peer in gray list...
D Destructing connection...
T [sock -1] Socket destroyed without shutdown.

All the errors keep looping.
If I am revealing anything sensitive on the pictures please let me know because doing this through complete clearnet which is risky for me.

I used the guide:
https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/vps_run_node.html
Linux64

FYI:
Before I launched the daemon I moved the items in Linux folder up on directory with command
mv monero-linux64/* monero-linux64/.*

The first part went through but there was an error that monero-linux/.* did not go through because to busy etc. That shouldn't matter right I just moved the stuff up one dir to the folder monero instead of keeping things two folders down idk.

Comment: Hey guys so turns out that what was wrong was that my Internet provider has blocking my certain connections.
For example at one point I read that I should execute "ping 8.8.8.8 and I received "packets were filtered" as a response.
So I had to get access to the internet through a different provider and now it is syncing like crazy. I guess the next question is how could I compare hashes of my node to other nodes just to make sure I have the right node. But I guessing maybe I don't have to do that?

Comment: You can, for example, use `print_block <blockheight>` in `monerod` and compare the block hash against the block hash listed on prominent block explorers.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the well-known blockchain explorers:
[xmrchain.net](https://xmrchain.net/) , [localmonero](https://localmonero.co/blocks) , [exploremonero](https://www.exploremonero.com/info)

In a terminal `./monerod print_height` shows your local blockchain height. Or use webbrowser `https://yournode.example.org:18081/get_info` See
[monerod-reference #commands](https://monerodocs.org/interacting/monerod-reference/#commands) for more useful things.

*Please ask your last question¹ again (and I'll put my answer there) so that it fits here on StackExchange. I still have too few points to comment, vote or edit others.*

> ¹How could I compare hashes of my node to other nodes just to make sure
> I have the right node.

Comment: Okay sorry I am super late and will post that last question.